# Replace lines and compile latex files in loop using python

Tags: latexmk, python

I have a LaTeX code in which there are multiple chapters that I compile individually. Sometimes I have to compile a lot of these files, and I'm trying to automate this process, instead of uncommenting, compiling and commenting, again the lines of the chapters. I also have to rename and put to another folder the chapter that I compiled.

I've managed to do write the code for a single chapter:

```
import os

texdoc = []

with open('aluno.tex') as fin:
   for line in fin:
        texdoc.append(line.replace('% \\include{chapters/funcoes}', '\\include{chapters/funcoes}'))

with open('aluno.tex', 'w') as fout:
    for i in range(len(texdoc)):
        fout.write(texdoc[i])

os.system("latexmk -pdfxe -c aluno.tex")

with open('aluno.tex', errors="ignore") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        texdoc.append(line.replace('\\include{chapters/funcoes}', '% \\include{chapters/funcoes}'))


# write back the new document
with open('aluno.tex', 'w', errors="ignore") as fout:
    for i in range(len(texdoc)):
        fout.write(texdoc[i])

os.rename('aluno.pdf','Introdução às Funções.pdf')

shutil.copy('Introdução às Funções.pdf', 'subfolder', follow_symlinks=True)
os.remove('Introdução às Funções.pdf')
```

What I'm trying to do now is to automate this process through a list of the chapters I want to compile. Something like

```
chapter = ["funcoes","taxa"]

name = ["Introdução às Funções", "Taxa de Variação"]

for j in chapter and k in name

   with open('aluno.tex') as fin:
   for line in fin:
        texdoc.append(line.replace('% \\include{chapters/j}', '\\include{chapters/j}'))
    
   os.rename('aluno.pdf','k.pdf')
```

How can I can achieve this with python?

Comment: I think your basic question is a python question and is better off at stackoverflow.

Comment: I posted it there, but thought that maybe someone here could have an answer.

Comment: Do you know `\includeonly`?  and the packages `docmute` and  `standalone`? Maybe your will find an easy way to make your previews.